# React native: Stomp websocket not working in android

Tags: android, reactjs, stomp-websocket

I try use https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket and https://github.com/JSteunou/webstomp-client

My server use Spring-boot

Mycode:

```
var Stomp = require('stompjs/lib/stomp.js').Stomp;
let client = Stomp.client(url);
client.connect({}, function connectCallback(frame){
   console.log('OK')
}, (error) => {
   console.log('Error');
});
```

Both working with IOS but in android this can't connect with server.

> Web Socket Opened...
>
> CONNECT
>
> accept-version:1.1,1.0
>
> heart-beat:10000,10000
>
> Whoops! Lost connection
>
> Error

Comment: Stomp wraps all messages adding Byte.NULL ('\x00') as a last symbol. Android implementation of WebSocket cuts last char if it is Byte.NULL (seems like a bug). However WebSocket.send could take a byte array as an argument, so basically all you need to do is to replace a string you pass to this method with an array of bytes, then everything would work right on both platforms.

Comment: here's a workaround that will solve your problem https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs/issues/55

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6449189/max) - problem is that android is not sending \x00.

Please check solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623125/1869260

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, it troubled me very much the last couple of days...

I had followed [Viktor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869260/viktor-yarmak) solution (which was also mentioned in many other sources as well from the research I did) about  Android implementation of WebSocket cuts last char if it is Byte.NULL and added to my server a wrapper for that extra character as most solutions suggest... but it still didn't work....

In the end it was a problem with my version of Android (9+) that does not allow clear text communication (i.e. no SSL) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22375)

Once, I added a self signed certificate on my development server it worked with no problems