# Socket.io between react native and java

Tags: java, react-native, socket.io

I want to create real-time data between my app in react native and the server in java. I was trying to do that with WebSocket but it didn't fix it.

I'm new with react native so I don't have a lot of knowledge. I'm looking for any guide which explains how to do that or any example, I have been looking and didn't find something clear.

**If you have any other options on how to do real-time data between react native and java I would like to hear**

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: @Rab I have been trying web socket but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert on these topics but I am working in a similar feature using React JS and Java (Spring boot). Lately I found a way to do that using Stomp and SockJS.

This is my code to React JS

```
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

...

  let timeout = 5000;
  let timeoutCounter = 0;
  const maxTimeoutCounter = 10;

  const connect = () => {

    const ws = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/socket");
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);

    let that = this;

    that.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {

      that.stompClient.subscribe("/queue/update", (message) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(message.body);
        // Some code here
      });

    }, (error) => {
      timeoutCounter++;

      if (timeoutCounter < maxTimeoutCounter) {
        setTimeout(connect, timeoutCounter * timeout);
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is part of my Java code to configure Spring Boot:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

      registry
         .addEndpoint("/socket")
         .setAllowedOrigins("*")
         .withSockJS();
   }

   public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

      registry
         .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
         .enableSimpleBroker("/queue/update");
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer... do you think it could work with react native? and where did you bring from 'stompjs' and 'sockjs-client' libraries? can you provide the code for  setTimeout function? and another question is how do you work with that in case you got a message? how do you running the render function again?

Comment: I think that should work in react-native. I installed the libraries using "npm install sockjs-client" and "npm install stompjs". The setTimeout function is a generic function of Javascript. When I receive the messages from server I just launch an redux action so the render method will be called when the redux state change.

Comment: Stomp in react native won't work in android.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598305/react-native-stomp-websocket-not-working-in-android